# Enabling a checkbox Tkinter (Python 3.4)

Tags: python, user-interface, checkbox, tkinter

I have a CheckBox in Tkinter. I want it to always stay checked but disabling the checkbox destroys the looks of the GUI application. I want to keep its state as Normal and if a user tries to uncheck it the box remains checked, or rechecks itself immediately after.

```
global ghistory
ghistory = IntVar()
cc = Checkbutton(frame3, text="History", variable=ghistory)
cc.select()
cc.pack()
```

How do I do it?

Comment: That sounds like a bad idea from a usability perspective

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a function that sets the variable to True. A quick lambda function would do the trick:

```
cc=tk.Checkbutton(frame3,text="History",variable=ghistory, command=lambda:ghistory.set(1))
```

Or you could use the `select` command:

```
cc=tk.Checkbutton(frame3,text="History",variable=ghistory)
cc['command'] = cc.select
```

Answer (score 0):

use .cget('state') to see if the button is disabled...

```
    self.widget_checkbutton = tk.Checkbutton(self, variable=self.some_variable, command=lambda:self.stay_checked())

    def stay_checked(self):
        if self.widget_checkbutton.cget('state') == 'disabled':
            self.widget_checkbutton.select()
        else:
            self.widget_checkbutton.deselect()
#this will only let the button be checked if widget is active.
```

(so basically, if some widget is disabled... you tell the checkbox to stay the same. else if some widget is normal, you allow the checkbox to work normally... select... deselect...)